# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): plugin_not_installed cordova plugin Filepath and File Chooser

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am Using FilePath And File Chooser Plugin to choose an attachment and convert it into base 64.

command Used to install Filepath:
npm install cordova-plugin-filepath
npm install @ionic-native/file-path

command used to install File Chooser
npm install cordova-plugin-filechooser
npm install @ionic-native/file-chooser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1uOE.png)

Comment: The error literally tells you what to do: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-filechooser`

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you haven't add the plugin to your package.json file. In order to do that in Ionic type this commands on a terminal opened in your project folder:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-filechooser
npm install @ionic-native/file-chooser
```